# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing small project using hibernate and MySQL.im getting this error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at com.sla.tecprof.daoImpl.LoginDAOImpl.getUser(LoginDAOImpl.java:22)
    at com.sla.tecprof.bdImpl.LoginBDImpl.getUser(LoginBDImpl.java:28)
    at com.sla.tecprof.bdImpl.LoginBDImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$798cbe95.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.sla.tecprof.bdImpl.LoginBDImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9f1f562a.getUser(<generated>)
    at com.sla.tecprof.action.LoginAction.validateUser(LoginAction.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:113)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`
my code is I think error is in buildSessonfactory.Is there any short way to check DB connection is success or not

```
List<Login> list = new ArrayList<Login>();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("From Login lg where lg.userName = :userName and  lg.password = password ");
        query.setParameter("userName", login.getUserName());
        query.setParameter("password", login.getPassword());
        list = query.list();
```

please help

My configuration file is :-

```
<beans>
<bean id="hibernateDataSourse" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tdp_management_system" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hibernateDataSourse" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.sla.tecprof.domain.Login</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I guess you are using Spring, why this line is there?                SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory(); You have already created one sessionFactory by the name of mySessionFactory try using it

Comment: Yes im using Spring sir. im new hibernate.I just use it for create sessionFactory object

Comment: Please check if your hibernate.cfg.xml file is in your classpath. Otherwise SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory(); cannot find the configuration file by default. Or you could specify the hibernate.cfg.xml location

Comment: Try injecting the session factory instance of "mySessionFactory" in your class for login. and then use that instance in place of building a new session factory

Comment: Thanx  Bilbo Baggins.You Show me the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have not used the `SessionFactory` Bean defined in your spring xml file, you have used your default configuration file instead of the spring bean as your `SessionFactory`.** Check your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, you have not added the property `hibernate.dialect` there.

Only thing I have to say is you are out of spring-mvc structure. So, follow the `mvc` structure with and use the session factory defined as a spring beans. Use spring dependency injection to set the `SessionFactory` in your java class as follows.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mySessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

If you are not need to follow `spring-mvc`, remove `SessionFactory` bean form your spring xml file and the `DataStore` also. Then define all settings with `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration file. But remember, don't build the `SessionFactory` every time when using. Use `static` or `ThreadLogical` Session factory for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of exception occurs mostly if your MySQL/Oracle Service is not started or connection to particular database machine is log off on network or locally does'not allow to take the connection while you specified the Hibernate dialect correct.So ensure the above things is proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating your SessionFactory through the traditional / utility class but not by Spring, you might consider using the following line:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

I second @Bilbo Baggins, when you've already configured sessionFactory in your Spring configuration, you could very well use **mysessionFactory** bean